# appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired - LinkedIn

Tags: php

I am getting this error. I have to get access token.

```
    {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"missing required parameters, includes an
 invalid parameter value, parameter more then once. : Unable to retrieve access token : appId 
or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired"}
```